# I would like to get the names of entire headers present in another fasta file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, bioinformatics

I have a fasta file like that :

```
>TRINITY_DN100_c0_g1_i1 len=242 path=[0:0-241]
AGCAATTCAAACTGCTGCAATCTGGGCTCGTGAAAACGATATGGTATTACACTTACATCGTGCAAGACAAACAACAAGTGCGTTACGTCACGTTACGTTAATTCGTTCGTTCGTCTCTCTATTGCGTTGCGTTACGCTCTCGCCGCGGACCCAGCACCGCATACCCGCCCATACAAGTCATACAGTACACAACACAAAAACACAACCAACTATTTCCTTGGAAGAGAAAGCAAGCCCAAAAC
>TRINITY_DN105_c0_g1_i1 len=260 path=[0:0-259]
TGAAAATATTAATTCTCAACCTTTTATGCGTTGGAGAGAAAGATATTTATTTTCAATAGAGGGAGTTAATCGTGCAGCGGCAGCAAGTGGTGAAATTAAAGGACATTATTTAAATGTTACTGCAGGTACAATGGAAGACATGTACGAACGCGCCAAGATTGATGTGCCTGAGAACCACATGAATAACGAGGAGCAATACACACTTCACTACCAAGAGTACCTTGTGGGTAGCTCGGCTGGTGTGCCCAAGGATATGAAGG
>TRINITY_DN103_c0_g1_i1 len=260 path=[0:0-259]
GTTCTCTTCGGTGGCAGCCTTACGGCCGACCACCTGGTATTGTCGCATAATTCCCGCAGCAGTCATGATGTCTATTGTTTGTCGTGAAAAGAAATGAATTAAGAGAGTCATAGTTACTCCCGCCGTTTACCCGCGCTTGGTTGAATTCCTTCACTTTGACATTCAGAGCACTGGGCAGAAATCACATTGCGTCAACACCATCTCTGTTTCAACGAAATCAGCAGTATCTGTAGAAGTGTAGTTAAAACTAATATCTTTCC
```

And I want to add the species names to the headers containing in an other fasta file using the beginning of the header and don't change the sequence of the first fasta.

```
>TRINITY_DN100_c0_g1_i1  HQ912515@Guinardia_delicatula
AGCAATCCAAACTGCTGCAATCTGGGCTCGTGAAAACGATATGGTATTACACTTACACCGTGC
>TRINITY_DN105_c0_g1_i1 KR048205@Mougeotia_transeaui
AGCAATTCAAAGTGCTGCAATCTGGGCTCGTGAAAACGATATGTTATTACACTTACACCGTGCA
>TRINITY_DN103_c0_g1_i1 RP957897@Luticola_sparsipunctata
AGCAATTCAAAGTGCTGCAATCTGGGCTCGTGAAAACGATATGATTTTACACTTACACCGTGCA
```

I would like something like that :

```
>TRINITY_DN100_c0_g1_i1 len=242 path=[0:0-241]@Guinardia_delicatula
AGCAATTCAAACTGCTGCAATCTGGGCTCGTGAAAACGATATGGTATTACACTTACATCGTGCAAGACAAACAACAAGTGCGTTACGTCACGTTACGTTAATTCGTTCGTTCGTCTCTCTATTGCGTTGCGTTACGCTCTCGCCGCGGACCCAGCACCGCATACCCGCCCATACAAGTCATACAGTACACAACACAAAAACACAACCAACTATTTCCTTGGAAGAGAAAGCAAGCCCAAAAC
>TRINITY_DN100_c0_g1_i1 len=260 path=[0:0-259]@Mougeotia_transeaui 
TGAAAATATTAATTCTCAACCTTTTATGCGTTGGAGAGAAAGATATTTATTTTCAATAGAGGGAGTTAATCGTGCAGCGGCAGCAAGTGGTGAAATTAAAGGACATTATTTAAATGTTACTGCAGGTACAATGGAAGACATGTACGAACGCGCCAAGATTGATGTGCCTGAGAACCACATGAATAACGAGGAGCAATACACACTTCACTACCAAGAGTACCTTGTGGGTAGCTCGGCTGGTGTGCCCAAGGATATGAAGG
>TRINITY_DN103_c0_g1_i1 len=260 path=[0:0-259]@Luticola_sparsipunctata
GTTCTCTTCGGTGGCAGCCTTACGGCCGACCACCTGGTATTGTCGCATAATTCCCGCAGCAGTCATGATGTCTATTGTTTGTCGTGAAAAGAAATGAATTAAGAGAGTCATAGTTACTCCCGCCGTTTACCCGCGCTTGGTTGAATTCCTTCACTTTGACATTCAGAGCACTGGGCAGAAATCACATTGCGTCAACACCATCTCTGTTTCAACGAAATCAGCAGTATCTGTAGAAGTGTAGTTAAAACTAATATCTTTCC
```

Do you have an idea how I can do?

Answer (score 0):

One way you can achieve what you describe is by:

1. Creating a mapping using the second file with headers
2. Reading the first file and replacing matching lines with the match from the mapping

Using awk, this would be for example:

```
awk -F@ 'NR == FNR { if ($0 ~ /^>/) { a[$1] = $0 }; next } { if ($0 ~ /^>/ && $0 in a) $0 = a[$0]; print }' second_file_with_headers first_file
```

Example:

```bsh
$ cat second_file_with_headers
>TRINITY_DN100_c0_g1_i1 len=242 path=[0:0-241]@Guinardia_delicatula
AGCAATCCAAACTGCTGCAATCTGGGCTCGTGAAAACGATATGGTATTACACTTACACCGTGC
>TRINITY_DN100_c0_g1_i1 KR048205>TRINITY_DN105_c0_g1_i1 len=260 path=[0:0-259]AGCAATTCAAAGTGCTGCAATCTGGGCTCGTGAAAACGATATGTTATTACACTTACACCGTGCA
>TRINITY_DN103_c0_g1_i1 len=260 path=[0:0-259]@Luticola_sparsipunctata
AGCAATTCAAAGTGCTGCAATCTGGGCTCGTGAAAACGATATGATTTTACACTTACACCGTGCA

$ cat first_file
>TRINITY_DN100_c0_g1_i1 len=242 path=[0:0-241]
AGCAATTCAAACTGCTGCAATCTGGGCTCGTGAAAACGATATGGTATTACACTTACATCGTGCAAGACAAACAACAAGTGCGTTACGTCACGTTACGTTAATTCGTTCGTTCGTCTCTCTATTGCGTTGCGTTACGCTCTCGCCGCGGACCCAGCACCGCATACCCGCCCATACAAGTCATACAGTACACAACACAAAAACACAACCAACTATTTCCTTGGAAGAGAAAGCAAGCCCAAAAC
>TRINITY_DN105_c0_g1_i1 len=260 path=[0:0-259]
TGAAAATATTAATTCTCAACCTTTTATGCGTTGGAGAGAAAGATATTTATTTTCAATAGAGGGAGTTAATCGTGCAGCGGCAGCAAGTGGTGAAATTAAAGGACATTATTTAAATGTTACTGCAGGTACAATGGAAGACATGTACGAACGCGCCAAGATTGATGTGCCTGAGAACCACATGAATAACGAGGAGCAATACACACTTCACTACCAAGAGTACCTTGTGGGTAGCTCGGCTGGTGTGCCCAAGGATATGAAGG
>TRINITY_DN103_c0_g1_i1 len=260 path=[0:0-259]
GTTCTCTTCGGTGGCAGCCTTACGGCCGACCACCTGGTATTGTCGCATAATTCCCGCAGCAGTCATGATGTCTATTGTTTGTCGTGAAAAGAAATGAATTAAGAGAGTCATAGTTACTCCCGCCGTTTACCCGCGCTTGGTTGAATTCCTTCACTTTGACATTCAGAGCACTGGGCAGAAATCACATTGCGTCAACACCATCTCTGTTTCAACGAAATCAGCAGTATCTGTAGAAGTGTAGTTAAAACTAATATCTTTCC

$ awk -F@ 'NR == FNR { if ($0 ~ /^>/) { a[$1] = $0 }; next } { if ($0 ~ /^>/ && $0 in a) $0 = a[$0]; print }' second_file_with_headers first_file
>TRINITY_DN100_c0_g1_i1 len=242 path=[0:0-241]@Guinardia_delicatula
AGCAATTCAAACTGCTGCAATCTGGGCTCGTGAAAACGATATGGTATTACACTTACATCGTGCAAGACAAACAACAAGTGCGTTACGTCACGTTACGTTAATTCGTTCGTTCGTCTCTCTATTGCGTTGCGTTACGCTCTCGCCGCGGACCCAGCACCGCATACCCGCCCATACAAGTCATACAGTACACAACACAAAAACACAACCAACTATTTCCTTGGAAGAGAAAGCAAGCCCAAAAC
>TRINITY_DN105_c0_g1_i1 len=260 path=[0:0-259]
TGAAAATATTAATTCTCAACCTTTTATGCGTTGGAGAGAAAGATATTTATTTTCAATAGAGGGAGTTAATCGTGCAGCGGCAGCAAGTGGTGAAATTAAAGGACATTATTTAAATGTTACTGCAGGTACAATGGAAGACATGTACGAACGCGCCAAGATTGATGTGCCTGAGAACCACATGAATAACGAGGAGCAATACACACTTCACTACCAAGAGTACCTTGTGGGTAGCTCGGCTGGTGTGCCCAAGGATATGAAGG
>TRINITY_DN103_c0_g1_i1 len=260 path=[0:0-259]@Luticola_sparsipunctata
GTTCTCTTCGGTGGCAGCCTTACGGCCGACCACCTGGTATTGTCGCATAATTCCCGCAGCAGTCATGATGTCTATTGTTTGTCGTGAAAAGAAATGAATTAAGAGAGTCATAGTTACTCCCGCCGTTTACCCGCGCTTGGTTGAATTCCTTCACTTTGACATTCAGAGCACTGGGCAGAAATCACATTGCGTCAACACCATCTCTGTTTCAACGAAATCAGCAGTATCTGTAGAAGTGTAGTTAAAACTAATATCTTTCC

$
```

---

The awk script can be explained fairly easily:

```bsh
awk         # the awk program, can be gawk, mawk or any other implementation
-F@         # Sets FS="@" . This tells awk to split on the @ character.
NR == FNR { if ($0 ~ /^>/) { a[$1] = $0 }; next }
   # While handling the first argument (here, second_file_with_headers)
   # For lines starting with >, store the line into an array with the part before @ as the key
   # Discard all lines in this file with 'next'
{ if ($0 ~ /^>/ && $0 in a) $0 = a[$0]; print }
   # For all other lines, meaning that we are now working on the second argument (first_file)
   # For lines starting with >, change the line into the stored version from the array if it exists
   # then print the line
second_file_with_headers
   # Use the file with the headers as the first argument
first_file
   # Use the file which needs to be updated as the second argument
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help :D But i realize that the file with the headers changed after manipulate it and i don't have the len and path in reality.. Do you know how i can do using my file like I repost ? Since long time i m trying to do it, but its totally a mess for me to find the good way.. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Sorry, I know you are a new user but you are not trying, you just want other people to work for you. Also, your question is now impossible to answer as we cannot know which line to match from the second file.

Comment: i understand your feeling, i ll try by my self, i m just broken for my analyse since few days now ! Thank you for your aid, i ll try to continue by the way you gave me

Comment: question is revised (clarified), you may need update your command/answer

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'[@[:blank:]]+' '
NR==FNR { if(/^>/) seen[$1]=$NF; next }
        { if($1 in seen) $0=$0 "@" seen[$1]; print }' second.fasta first.fasta
```

with `-F` we can specify the **F**ield separator that we set to `@` character and also whitespaces ( `[:blank:]` Tabs/Spaces) where they can occur one-or-more times `[...]+`; so fields would be separated with these characters.

`NF==FNR` is a always true condition in *awk* that is true for first input file always (*second.fasta* file here); `NR` and `FNR` are incrementing for each line of input but `FNR` reset back to 1 for next input file.

this `if(/^>/)` is a condition that checks if the line starts (`^` in regex point to the begging of the line) with a `>` character, if so, then hold the last field `$NF` into an associated array (we name it `seen`) and filed #1 `$1` would use as the keys.

the `next` statement skip processing the rest of the codes and jump to the begging of the code again; if `NR==FNR` condition was still true, it will repeats the following code `NR==FNR { ... }` else next block will be executed and that is performing on the second input file *first.fasta* which we checks if the first field in it can be found in the `seen` array or not, if yes, then append at the end of that line the value of the found key and next do `print` whatever it is in whole line `$0` (either it's updated or not).

---

Or if all the headers in both files are represent and also are in the same line number, you could do as following instead of buffering *second.fasta* file into memory:

```
paste -d@ first.fasta second.fasta |awk -F@ '/^>/{ $1=$1 $NF } { print $1 }'
```

Comment: Its exactly what i wanted ! Thanks a lot ! Hopefully i ll improve my bio informatic skills i just began on it :D The first script work perfectly !

Comment: @Léa please consider reading https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers